# Exclude my REST APIs from site authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity

I have an ASP.NET Core application with both web pages and APIs (using controllers).

It's working fine except, right now, if I attempt to access an API, I get redirected to the login page.

I'd like my API to be accessible without logging in. But I want my web pages to continue working as they do now.

I omitted the `[Authorize]` attribute from my controller and thought that would be enough. I'm not sure I understand why it wasn't.

Is there an easy setting for this?

Comment: How is the authentication/authorization enforced?  Are you using `[Authorize]` and/or `[AllowAnonymous]` attributes on your controllers/actions?

Comment: @David: I'm using neither. I thought omitting `[Authorize]` would do the trick, but apparently not.

Comment: Applying ```[AllowAnonymous]``` to the API controllers should produce the behaviour that you want

Comment: If you wish that all your controllers and actions do not require login you can try setting the `AllowAnonymous` when mapping the controllers. For example:
`app.MapControllers().AllowAnonymous();`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like`[AllowAnonymous]` does what I want. Need some additional testing.